# Compose custom shadow not working on Android 6

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I create custom shadow with modifier extension function. It is giving perfect output on other Android versions. But some of the older Android versions such as Android OS version 6 it is not showing any shadow. Modifier extension function looks like this :

```
fun Modifier.advancedShadow() = composed {
    val color = Color.SomeColor
    drawBehind {
        val shadowColor = color.copy(alpha = 0.10f).toArgb()
        val transparentColor = Color.Black.copy(alpha = 0f).toArgb()
        drawIntoCanvas {
            val paint = Paint()
            val frameworkPaint = paint.asFrameworkPaint()
            frameworkPaint.color = transparentColor
            frameworkPaint.setShadowLayer(
                12.dp,
                0.dp,
                1.dp,
                shadowColor
            )
            it.drawRoundRect(
                0f,
                0f,
                this.size.width,
                this.size.height,
                cornerRadius.toPx(),
                cornerRadius.toPx(),
                paint
            )
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `setShadowLayer()` function is supported for text only when hardware acceleration is enabled.

I use `Modifier.shadow(...)` from `androidx.compose.ui.draw` for **sdk < Q** and it works. It has all the parameters to make beautiful shadows on older devices!

> ```
> @Stable fun Modifier.shadow(
>     elevation: Dp,
>     shape: Shape = RectangleShape,
>     clip: Boolean = elevation > 0.dp,
>     ambientColor: Color = DefaultShadowColor,
>     spotColor: Color = DefaultShadowColor, 
> )
> ```